# php regex issue

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract a substring from a string.

I have strings like this:

```
English !'O!Kung Proper noun # A northern variety of the [[!Kung]] [[dialect]] [[continuum]], now principally found in northern Namibia.
```

or:

```
English & Conjunction # {{abbreviation of|and}}
```

These are only two examples.

What I want is to get the word and its part of speech.
E.g.:

- !'O!Kung - Proper noun
- & - Conjunction

I came up with this regex: `/English (.*) (Proper noun|Conjunction)+/i`

However it doesn't seem to work. Any idea? :)

### UPDATE:

I figured out that this one works: `/English\s+(.*)\s+(Proper noun|Conjunction)+/i`

Comment: Your first regex is working fine in javascript, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq4sj/) for demo. The issue must be how PHP is handling the spaces.

Comment: For the benefit of the community, you should make the one that works an answer and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Your first one should also be working, if the whitspace in the string and in the pattern are the same, that means e.g. a space in both cases. If it is a tab in your string and a space in your pattern it will not work.

Comment: That's why I was confused. I came up with the regex on Rubular.com but it still had to be adjusted to work with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that this one works well in PHP: `/English\s+(.*)\s+(Proper noun|Conjunction)+/i`